# customize url of path of file entity

Tags: 7, path-aliases, media, uri

I'm using the media module to build an imagebank.
Is there a way to customize the url of a file? Currently is looks like this: `file/20` and I would like t to look like this `imagebank/image/20`.

Any ideas?

thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File entity doesn't currently integrate with Pathauto but integration is being worked on in [Add support for Pathauto](http://drupal.org/node/1296744).

Please help test the latest patch and provide feedback including if it works correctly and any issues you might have found!

Comment: Thx Devin.
The patch seems to do the trick. I'll run some more tests laters on.